# How to display items in a sorted order?

Tags: django-templates

I have this in my template file:

```
{% get_latest_show as slideshow %}
{% for slide in slideshow.slide_set.all %}
<a href="{{slide.target_url}}"><img src="{% thumbnail slide.image 1174x640 upscale %}" alt="{{slide.title}}" width="1174"/></a>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Slide(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    target_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slideshow = models.ForeignKey('Slideshow')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='slideshow', max_length=500, blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Slideshow(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-title']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

slide_tags.py

```
from django import template
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from slides.models import Slide, Slideshow

register = template.Library()

class GetSlideshowNode(template.Node):
    """
    Retrieves the latest published slideshow
    """
    def __init__(self, varname):
        self.varname = varname

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            show = Slideshow.objects.filter(published=True)[0]
        except:
            show = []

        context[self.varname] = show
        return ''

def get_latest_show(parser, token):
    """
    Retrieves the latest published slideshow

    {% get_latest_show as show %}
    """
    args = token.split_contents()
    argc = len(args)

    try:
        assert (argc == 3 and args[1] == 'as')
    except AssertionError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError('get_latest_show syntax: {% get_latest_show as varname %}')

    varname = None
    t, a, varname = args

    return GetSlideshowNode(varname=varname)

register.tag(get_latest_show)
```

The problem is that my slides are being displayed out of order. When I print slideshow.slide.set.all on the page, I see:

```
[<Slide: Slide 2>, <Slide: Slide 3>, <Slide: Slide 4>, <Slide: Slide 1>]
```

How do I get the slides to appear in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `slide_set` to be ordered therefor the 'ordering' statement should be on the `Slide` model.

```
class Slide(models.Model):
    # fields
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-title']
```

This will cause `Slide.objects.all()` to return a queryset ordered by the `title` field. That is equivalent to `slideshow.slide_set.all()`

Comment: thanks for the reply but I tried putting it in views.py with no luck. I've updated the question with more context. The views.py in the folder is empty.

Comment: @khwebdesigns I missed that you were using a template tag. I updated my answer above. Hope it will solve it.

Comment: @khwebdesigns Glad to be of help. Happy Djangoing!